# Inserting Data w/ session data into database using Codeigniter

Tags: php, html, sql-server, bootstrap-modal, codeigniter-3

Im having trouble in troubleshooting this problem, I want to save the searched data using input function and pass the id of it into the controller but im having a problem about it,

This is my Controller:

```
function add($id){
            $this->point_m->addStudentSection($id);
            redirect('admins_view/points/index');
        }
```

This is my Model:

```
function addStudentSection($id){
        $arr['section_id'] = $this->session->userdata('section_id');
        $arr['dateadded'] = $this->input->post('dateadded');
        $arr['schoolyear'] = $this->input->post('schoolyear');
        $arr['semester'] = $this->input->post('semester');
        $arr['point'] = $this->input->post('point');

        $this->db->where('student_id',$id);
        $this->db->insert('section_student',$arr);


    }
```

in case that model above is wrong here's my other model function that i'am also using, also i am using sqlsrv for my database.

```
function addStudentSection($id){
            $arr['section_id'] = $this->session->userdata('section_id');
            $arr['dateadded'] = $this->input->post('dateadded');
            $arr['schoolyear'] = $this->input->post('schoolyear');
            $arr['semester'] = $this->input->post('semester');
            $arr['point'] = $this->input->post('point');

            $query = $this->db->query("

                INSERT INTO [dbo].[section_student]
               ([student_id]
               ,[section_id]
               ,[dateadded]
               ,[schoolyear]
               ,[semester]
               ,[point])
                VALUES
               ('$id'
               ,'$section_id'
               ,'$dateadded'
               ,'$schoolyear'
               ,'$semester'
               ,'$point')

                ");


        }
```

so in this model i want to use also my section_id which is an session

This is my view :

```
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>ID Number</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Middlename</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Total Points</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <?php
    foreach ($pt as $p) {
  ?>
    <tr>
      <!-- echo query with join -->
      <td><?php echo $p->idnumber ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p->firstname ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p->middlename ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p->lastname ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $p->point ?></td>
      <td>
        <a href="<?php echo site_url('admins/point/add').'/'.'$p->id';?>" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Add</a> 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Redeem</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

In this table lies all the searched and retrieve datas from my display function as you can see the button to toggle is a modal.
this is my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admins/point/add">
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add Point/s</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <label>Date</label>
          <input type="date" name="dateadded" class="form-control">
          <label>School year</label>
          <select name="schoolyear" class="form-control">
          <option value="2018-2019">2018-2019</option>
          <option value="2019-2020">2019-2020</option>
          </select>
          <label>Semester</label>
          <select name="semester" class="form-control">
            <option value="1st">First Semester</option>
            <option value="2nd">Second Semester</option>
            <option value="summer">Summer</option>
          </select>
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="text" name="point" class="form-control">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

and this is the error response..
[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfHzt.png)
Hope anyone from the community can help me,.

Comment: you need to pass 1 parameter to function add

Comment: check points.php in line no 25

Comment: this is my line no 25 function add($id){

Comment: is there wrong in my passing of parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Because your controller add($id) expected 1 parameter, then in modal view you can't set form action like this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admins/point/add">
```

Change your form action to this:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admins/point/add/$id">
```

Change `$id` with your parameter.

Here the [docs](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html).

Answer (score 0):

you should add the id at the end of form action in your view.

or you can remove it from your function in controller and post it as a hidden input

so change your view to

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>admins/point/add/$id">
```

or go to your controller and change it to

```
function add($id = null){
    if($id == null){
        $id = $this->input->post('id');
    }
}
```

then ad a new hidden input to your view right before form close tag like this

```
<?php echo form_hidden('id',$the_id);?>
```